# Verify that a provided value is an instance of Lodash

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js, lodash, mixins

Im working on a JS module that requires an instance of Lodash to be handed to it. I want to check that the variable handed to it is in fact an instance of lodash, but i'm having a hard time doing that....

Heres the console output of me trying various ways to get it:

```
_.all()
true
_.identity
Ut(n){return n}
_.identity.name
"Ut"
_.name
"J"
_.prototype.name
undefined
_.prototype.constructor.name
"J"
_.findIndex.prototype.name
undefined
_.constructor.isPrototypeOf(_)
false
_.isPrototypeOf(_)
false
_.isPrototypeOf(_.constructor)
false
_.isPrototypeOf(_.prototype)
false
_.constructor.prototype.name
""
_.prototype.name
undefined
_.isPrototypeOf( new _ )
false
_.__proto__.__proto__.constructor.name
"Object"
_.__proto__.constructor.name
"Function"
_.constructor.name
"Function"
_.prototype.constructor.name
"Ot"
```

Now if check if `_` is an instance of `_.constructor`, like so:

```
_ instanceof _.constructor
true
```

That will obviously say yes. But thats like asking "Are you... you?.."

So is there a way to check if a specific variable is an instance of Lodash?

Thanks!

Comment: counter point: no you don't. Your consuming code only technically cares that the functions it will be calling are defined, and you personally only care about the fact that they do what you expect them to do as part of lodash. There is no requirement to test for "a lodash instance", just test to make sure the functions you'll need are available. But it'd be even better to write your code so that you *know* your code has lodash available, instead of passing it in later. A globally available (literal global, or module) lodash trumps passing around instances every time.

Comment: Agreed, OP doesn't articulate *why* one would even want to do this.

Comment: I would want to do this to make sure the argument passed to the function, is  an instance of lodash... Im creating a module that has a lot of "helpers" for Mongoose, and I wanted to give users the option of passing it an instance of lodash, which would then merge the Mongoose helpers into that lodash instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the best solution is to go for the [version](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.2#VERSION) information, could save you some trouble with the differences between versions as well. Other than that, what I've seen is people looking for some specific methods they expect to find on the library.

Comment: Thats actually something I thought about doing, but thats not exactly conclusive, so it would be a "last resort" kinda thing.